# How to make a cup/bowl like shape in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web

I am currently using the package **curved_navigation_bar: ^0.4.0-nullsafety.0** to display a navigation bar in my flutter project.

currently the default shape of selected icon looks like this

[image]

I want something that looks like this

[image]

when I go into the source code I see some mathematical formulas which I tried tweaking but am not getting a similar result. can someone help me? a container or widget of this exact shape will also help me. thanks